# jquery scroll to the bottom

Tags: jquery, scroll, chat

I'm making a chat program.

And all the chat messages are inside the chat_viewport div.

THe problem is, i want to automatically scroll bottom to the scrollbox, when the page is refreshed.

I googled a lot of codes, but all of them aren't working :(

This is my html

```
 <div id="chat_viewport">
        <ul style="height:380px; overflow:auto" id="chat">
            <li>
                test: 123123123213&nbsp;&nbsp;(2013-07-22 12:51:36)
            </li>
            <li>
                test: gogogo&nbsp;&nbsp;(2013-07-22 13:32:58)
            </li>
            <li>
                test: ddddd&nbsp;&nbsp;(2013-07-22 13:33:48)
            </li>
            <li>
                test: ddddd&nbsp;&nbsp;(2013-07-22 13:33:48)
            </li>
            <li>
                test: ddddd&nbsp;&nbsp;(2013-07-22 13:33:48)
            </li>
            <li>
                test: ddddd&nbsp;&nbsp;(2013-07-22 13:33:50)
            </li>
            <li>
                test: asdfasdfsdf&nbsp;&nbsp;(2013-07-22 13:36:36)
            </li>
            <li>
                test: new one&nbsp;&nbsp;(2013-07-22 13:37:30)
            </li>
            <li>
                test: testsetest&nbsp;&nbsp;(2013-07-22 13:37:58)
            </li>
            <li>
                test: ddddd&nbsp;&nbsp;(2013-07-22 13:40:11)
            </li>
            <li>
                test: sadfasdf&nbsp;&nbsp;(2013-07-22 13:40:51)
            </li>

            <li>
                admin: ccc&nbsp;&nbsp;(2013-07-26 15:12:37)
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I tried

```
 $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $('#chat').offset().top + $('#chat').outerHeight(true) - $(window).height()
}, 500);
$('#chat').scrollTop($('#chat_viewport')[0].scrollHeight);
$("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $('#chat').offset().top - ($(window).height() - $("#chat").outerHeight() + 10)
}, 500);
  $("#chat").animate({
                scrollTop: $("#chat").scrollHeight
            }, 1000);
```

tried both #chat and #chat_viewport, but all of them aren't working :(

Comment: `$(window).on('load',function(){});` did you try loading this on window load?

Comment: manoz // nope not working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the overflow on #chat the height itself gets limited to 380px so there's nothing to scroll from. I moved the overflow to the #chat_viewport

```
<div id="chat_viewport" style="height:380px; overflow:auto">
    <ul id="chat">
        <li>..</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then something like this would work:

```
var chat_height = $('#chat').outerHeight();
$('#chat_viewport').scrollTop(chat_height);
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/atRkJ/